# Unable to connect to network, posting log. What could be the problem? OS Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

```
15.09.2015 22:57:52.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 22:57:52.400 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Darth\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
15.09.2015 22:57:52.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
15.09.2015 22:57:52.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
15.09.2015 22:57:53.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
15.09.2015 22:57:53.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
15.09.2015 22:57:53.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
15.09.2015 22:57:55.700 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 1 hours, 3 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
15.09.2015 22:57:55.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
15.09.2015 22:57:55.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
15.09.2015 22:57:56.500 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 1 hours, 3 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
15.09.2015 22:57:56.500 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 2 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-09-15 20:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
15.09.2015 22:57:56.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
15.09.2015 22:59:31.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 22:59:31.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
15.09.2015 22:59:31.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 22:59:32.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
15.09.2015 22:59:34.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 23:00:28.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 23:00:28.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
15.09.2015 23:00:28.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15.09.2015 23:00:29.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly this:

```
15.09.2015 22:57:56.500 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 1 hours, 3 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
15.09.2015 22:57:56.500 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 2 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-09-15 20:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
```

With the suggested action in the above logs being:

```
Please check your time and date settings!
```

Comment: So do i need to change system time, or just Windows? Right now it is in order...